# Setting normals using Python API causes normals to reset

Tags: python, normals

I have an extremely peculiar issue.

Basically, as a test, I tried to set my mesh's custom normals to themselves. Nothing special. Should result in an identical mesh.

However -

This is what my mesh looks like before I set the normals through the API: [image]

And this is what it looks after I set the normals to *themselves*:[image]

And the code:

```py
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

normals = []
for v in me.vertices:
    normals.append(v.normal)

me.normals_split_custom_set_from_vertices(normals)
```

For some reason, this simple code actually *resets the normals of the mesh.* (I checked, these "new" normals depicted in the second image are actually identical to the default generated normals)

I think this is because `v.normal` doesn't return the actual custom normal but the generated normal of the mesh, but only on this mesh in specific. Why?

If it matters, the custom normals were made using the [built-in Copy Vectors and Paste Vectors tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html). I can't tell if I'm doing something horribly wrong or if those built-in tools just break my mesh for whatever reason.

Help would be incredibly appreciated.

[You can download the file here](https://send.firefox.com/download/1c4b2cab03ef2ff9/#M4Iiz5hr8aTI8ugU9bNOWA), just select "Typhlosion" object then execute the "set_normals" script in the Scripting tab to see the effect.